# Efficient svn checkout in docker container

Tags: docker, svn, docker-compose

I want to checkout some files (specifically, test suite http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/test-suite/trunk) in my docker container.

Now I just use `RUN svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/test-suite/trunk train.out/llvm-test-suite` inside Dockerfile.

It works, but doesn't look efficient: on each docker-compose I need to wait for ~5 minutes while the tests are loading.
Is there a better way to prevent Docker from checking out this file each time? The only alternative I see for now is including the file into container.

Comment: I know very little about svn, but attaching the checked out project directory as a volume to the container doesn't help?

Comment: An interesting question is why Docker layer caching _isn’t_ caching this.  You often don’t want that (it won’t repeat the `svn co` even if something has changed in the remote repository) but as you’ve described things that should be happening and Docker shouldn’t on its own be repeating this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don’t run source-control tools from inside a Dockerfile.  Check them out in a host directory (better still, if you can manage it, add the `Dockerfile` directly to the repository you’re trying to build) and run `docker build` with all of its inputs directly on disk.

There are a couple of good reasons for this:

- Docker image caching can often mean that Docker won’t repeat a “clone”, “checkout”, or “pull” type operation: it knows it’s done it once and already knows the output of it and skips the step, even if there are new commits you don’t have.
- Adding tools like `svn` or `git` to the image that you only need to build it makes it unnecessarily larger.  (Multi-stage builds can avoid this, but they’re relatively new.)
- The more common use case for this is to clone a private repository that needs credentials, and it’s hard to avoid leaking those credentials into the final image.  (Again multi-stage builds can avoid this, with some care, but it’s better to not have the security exposure at all.)